# sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting, regular-expression

I have a big file to which I am doing various operations, and this error just came up. I tried googling it but there didn't find any result with this.

```
sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX
```

My purpose is to quote every line, appending a comma,
and subsequently enclose the entirety of the file with square brackets
(as a single line). 
For example, an input of

```
The quick brown fox
jumps over
the lazy dog.
```

should yield a result of

```
["The quick brown fox","jumps over","the lazy dog.",]
```

Assume that the input file doesn’t contain any quotes.

The code I run is this:

```
cat "${FILE}" | sed -e 's/.*/"&",/' | sponge "${FILE}"

truncate --size=-1 "${FILE}"

cat "${FILE}" |  sed -z 's/.*/[&]/' | tr --delete '\n' | sponge "${FILE}"
```

sed version:

```
sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.5
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: without the expression, you'll get less useful answers.

Comment: @ThomasDickey updated the post with the sed expression

Comment: It's an unanchored regular expression, matching everything without limits, and quoting, then adding a character after each match.  That sounds consistent with the error message.  By the way, programming questions are in a different forum.

Comment: @ThomasDickey My purpose is to quote every line and subsequently enclose the entirety of the file with square brackets. What alternative solution would you chose to do that with sed? It worths noting that it works sometimes, and sometimes it throws this error. Also sorry if it is the wrong forum.

Comment: hint: **`^`** and **`$`** are useful anchors.

Comment: Rather than slurping the whole file into memory (using `-z`) why not insert the `[` at the start of the first line and the `]` at the end of the last? `sed -e '1s/^/[/' -e '$s/$/]/'`

Comment: @ThomasDickey: (1) Yes, the regular expressions in Chris’s commands are “unanchored” — they don’t begin with `^` or end with `$`. What does that have to do with the question? How does that comment help the OP? (2) Command line utilities are on-topic at U&L. So are shell scripts, within reason; a three-line script is certainly reasonable for discussion here. (3) We prefer not to use the word “forum” when talking about [SE].

Comment: @steeldriver thank you for the snippet. It worked well.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is strange. 
You say “… this error just came up. 
I tried googling it but there didn't find any result with this.”,
making it sound like you have no idea what’s happening. 
But you do understand it, don’t you? 
When you say `sed -z`, you’re telling `sed` to read the input,
treating NUL as record (line) separators instead of newline. 
But text files typically don’t have NUL characters in them,
so, in practical terms,
this means that you want `sed` to read the entire file
and treat it as one line. 
You obviously understand this; your `'s/.*/[&]/'` command,
to “enclose the entirety of the file with square brackets”,
doesn’t make sense unless you expect the entirety of the file
to be treated as a single line.

So why are you so surprised that your big file
is too big to be handled as a single line?

You say that your script works sometimes —
presumably when the size of the file
is below the maximum line size permitted by `sed`. 
This script should do the same thing, regardless of the size of the file:

```
cat "$FILE" | sed -e 's/.*/"&",/' -e '1s/^/[/' -e '$s/$/]/' | tr --delete '\n'
```

Of course this can still choke if any individual *line* in the input
is absurdly long.

Notes:

- You don’t need the `{` and `}`; `"$FILE"` is fine.
- Following [the suggestion made by steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453507/80216#comment823950_453507),
  this inserts a `[` at the beginning of the first line
  and appends a `]` at the end of the last line.
- I left off the `sponge` for illustration purposes. 
  Overwriting your input file may be operationally necessary,
  but it’s a bad thing to do while you’re still debugging. 
  Add the `sponge` command back when you’re sure it’s doing what you want.

This duplicates your script, so an input of

```
The quick brown fox
jumps over
the lazy dog.
```

will yield a result of

```
["The quick brown fox","jumps over","the lazy dog.",]
```

with an extra comma before the `]`. 
If that’s really what you want, OK, that’s fine with me. 
If you don’t want the comma at the end, do

```
cat "$FILE" | sed -e 's/.*/"&",/' -e '1s/^/[/' -e '$s/,$/]/' | tr --delete '\n'
```

where the `'$s/,$/]/'` command
removes the comma at the end of the file when it appends the `]`.

Note also that all of the commands discussed so far
will leave you with a file with no newline characters,
***not even one at the end***. 
This is a malformed text file,
and some commands my fail to process it properly. 
If that’s really what you want, OK, that’s fine with me. 
Otherwise, add

```
echo >> "$FILE"
```

or

```
printf '\n' >> "$FILE"
```

at the end of your script.

Comment: The output file is supposed to be consumed by other programs as a json array. Do you think the new line is going to play a role in that? thank you for your input. Also please note that I was unaware of the term buffer in the context of the message and what the -z flag was really doing, hence my confusion on this. Thank you for clearing it up. Finally yes, I want the command at the end to be gone, that's why I used truncate

Comment: ** the comma at the end

Comment: (1) I’m not very familiar with JSON or the programs that manipulate it.  It’s possible that they won’t care about the missing newline.  In particular, if you’ve gotten Program *X* to work with the output from your current script, you probably won’t have any trouble with it in the future. (2) I invite you to run your script (the one you posted in the question) again, on a small sample input (e.g., “The quick brown fox …”).  I think you’ll find that the extra comma is there; the `truncate --size=-1` removes only the final newline.  Try running `sed -z 's/.*/[&]/'` on a small file for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't require sed, awk can do this, IMHO a bit more clearly:

Edit: original method (fixed by G-Man, tnx), which I based on looking at the sample output in the Q WITH comma after last string:

```
 awk <"$FILE" -vORS= -vq=\" 'BEGIN{print "["} {print q $0 q ","} END{print "]\n"}' | sponge "$FILE"
```

- as G-Man said, leave off the `sponge` part for debugging
- if you don't want the newline at the end, leave out the `\n`

Add: modified method, based on the request to remove the last comma before adding the brackets:

```
 awk <"$FILE" -vORS= -vq=\" 'BEGIN{print "["} {print sep q $0 q; sep=","} END{print "]\n"}' | sponge "$FILE"
```

(In awk an uninitialized variable in string context is guaranteed to yield an empty string, but if you prefer to be explicit add `-vsep=` to the options or `;sep=""` to the `BEGIN` block to initialize it.)

Comment: got unexpected newline or end of string, hmm let's see

Comment: @Chris: I fixed the “unexpected newline or end of string” problem.

Comment: dave_thompson_085: Your solution behaves the same as the first command in my answer — it includes a comma after the last line of input (``"the lazy dog."``), before the `]` — which Chris doesn’t want.  Can you remove that?

Comment: @G-Man: tnx and done